# Why registry value doesn't match in winreg in Python 3 on Windows?

Tags: python-3.x, registry, winreg

Hello everybody!

I am coding small python3 project. In my code, there's a function to check whether a user has installed specific DirectX version or not.

That function is as below.

```
def check_directx():
    try:
        reg_obj = OpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False

    dx_value_str = EnumValue(reg_obj, 1)[1][0:4]
    CloseKey(reg_obj)

    if dx_value_str != "4.09":
        return False

    return True
```

I wanted to test this function so I changed the original version value(4.09.00.0904) to 4.07.00.0904 in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX*. But it didn't work. variable dx_value_str's value was still 4.09.00.0904.

I searched registry and found that there's a same key, value in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectX*. I changed the version value of here, variable dx_value_str's value has been changed at last.

As you see, I opened the key in 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX' But it brought the value in 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DirectX'.

Is this situation all right? or there's something wrong in my code?

Please help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is because you might be using 32 bit python,try this:

```
import winreg
reg_obj = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DirectX',0, (winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY+ winreg.KEY_READ))
dx_value_str = winreg.EnumValue(reg_obj, 1)[1][0:4]
print(dx_value_str)
winreg.CloseKey(reg_obj)
```